# Does Photoshop Elements 10 support a Dual Monitor configuration?

Tags: software, monitors, photoshop-elements

Does Adobe PhotoShop Elements 10 Support Dual Monitors?  Bing searching only seems to provide links for how to setup dual monitors in full blown photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

Lightroom seems to be aware of the existence of a second monitor, and has specific menu actions for placing windows there.  However, a program doesn't have to be aware of dual monitors, as long as it has child windows that can be moved around outside the main frame, they can be moved across into a second monitor. It's handled by the operating system and display adapters, which is most likely oblivious to the fact there are two monitors involved.

I don't use Elements, but it seems to have dockable, movable palettes and toolbars like Photoshop CSx, so I would imagine the answer is yes.

There is anecdotal evidence in [this](http://www.elementsvillage.com/forums/showthread.php?t=50546) thread that users have been using dual monitors since Elements 7.

Comment: Good points, but I'm not sure if docking palletes will work for me.   I have about 10,000 pictures on my HD and I need a Full Screen preview mode for my low res TV to keep my kids of my back while I edit pictures in my smaller hi-res monitor.  PhotoDirector by Cyberlink makes this task a cinch for me, but PhotoDirector is missing a few things that PSE has.  So it looks like I have to continue using multiple programs to meet my photo management needs.  If it weren't for my family, I would probably only have a few hundered photos...

Comment: I think Adobe offer a 30-day trial of Elements, you could have a look.  I know with Photoshop you can open a 2nd copy of the image you're working on, so for example you can zoom in on a section of the image and do editing, but still see the full image preview in another window.  That other window could be moved to a different monitor, if that's what you're talking about.  Whether Elements allows the same thing I don't know.